# What is the best method for dynamically resizing svg files?

Tags: javascript, svg, resize, transformation, hammer.js

I am working with the hammer.js touch functions to develop a pinch zoom and drag for svg files.  I know there are multiple ways to resize an svg file which are different than how a typicaly jpg or png would be modified.  I'm wondering which of these methods would work best for the pinch zoom using hammer.js.  I am not modifying individual elements within the svg, rather I am modifying the entire svg file.

One, I could change the x, y, width, and height values of the svg.  Two, I can add scale transformation with a setAttribute() call.  Or, three, I can modify the viewbox element properties.  A fourth option could be to do a combination of one or more of these.

Is there one option which works particularly better than others?

Thank you, 
--Christopher

- Edit **  Adding an jsfiddle svg example.
  http://jsfiddle.net/LM2U6/

  `<svg version="1.1" style="border:1px solid #00f;" id="testsvg" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin slice" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 200 200" enable-background="new 0 0 200 200" xml:space="preserve">
     <rect x="75" y="75" width="50" height="50" style="stroke: #3333cc; fill:none;" />
   </svg>
   <svg version="1.1" style="border:1px solid #00f;" id="testsvg4" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin slice"  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="200" height="200" viewBox="50 50 100 100" xml:space="preserve" >
     <rect x="75" y="75" width="50" height="50" style="stroke: #3333cc; fill:none;" />
   </svg>
   <svg        version="1.1"        id="testsvg2"        style="border:1px solid #00f;"         preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin slice"        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"        xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"        x="0px"       y="0px"       width="400"        height="400"        viewBox="0 0 200 200"        enable-background="new 0 0 200 200"          xml:space="preserve">
     <rect x="75" y="75" width="50" height="50" style="stroke: #3333cc; fill:none;" />
   </svg> 
   <svg       version="1.1"        style="transform:matrix(2,0,0,2,100,100);border:1px solid #00f;"        id="testsvg3"        preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin slice"        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"        xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"        x="0px"       y="0px"       width="200"        height="200"        viewBox="0 0 200 200"        enable-background="new 0 0 200 200"        xml:space="preserve">
     <rect x="75" y="75" width="50" height="50" style="stroke: #3333cc; fill:none;" />
   </svg>`

From the example, you can see the original svg image.  The 2nd image changes the viewbox which basically zooms the entire contents by 2.  It keeps the size of the svg viewport the same.  The 3rd image is zoomed in by doubling the width and height properties.  The last image zoomed in by setting the transform scale property.  The last two images double the view port size of the svg.

Comment: Those things are not the same. Try them out and you'll see.

Comment: They are not the same, but can all visually simulate zooming in or out.  I edited my original post to include a jsfiddle which shows how each method can essentially zoom an svg file.

Comment: Best is subjective but SVG does provide native zoom capability via the currentScale and currentTranslate fields of the outer `<svg>` element.

Comment: In my testing, all three methods have advantages and disadvantages.  I like the flexibility of modifying the width and height.  I can increase the width until it hits the current document width.  However, if part of the image goes past the page width, it is clipped and if the images is then sized back down, the clipped portion is never redrawn.  The viewbox method does not allow the size of the viewport to be changed which I need on occasion.  And the Scale method causes the elements of the svg to overlap other html elements outside of the svg border.

Answer (score 1):

Ok a few thigns that might help you

1--- create a global svg container and set is dimensions as it going to be your view port

2--- create a single g element to take the entire viewport.

3--- inside the g element insert all other elements that will be displayed

## panning and zooming

as simple as modifying the transform property on the higher level g element zooming in actually scales over 100% zomming out scales under 100 and panning just does translation